# What iOS games use multi-touch in an innovative way?

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, games

I am looking for iOS games which use multi-touch in such a way that is not possible to emulate on other systems. This does not include games that use multi-touch to emulate a button and analog stick controller. So far I have found these apps:

- [Eliss](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/eliss/id306950009?mt=8) - pinch in and out to combine planets
- [Sway](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sway/id302900092?mt=8) - Left/Right side of screen to dedicated to each arm of the character
- [Cross Fingers](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cross-fingers/id337490369?mt=8) - Must use multiple fingers on some levels to hold blocks out of the way

Comment: If you don't think this question is on topic please comment why. Also see this meta post: http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/144/are-iphone-app-requests-on-topic

Comment: Downvoting without commenting as to why is *not cool*.

Comment: @Philip Voting is anonymous _by design._ Since you complained, however - yes, I downvoted. No, I don't _have to_ explain why. Since you asked, however - I think this question is the product of idle curiosity, rather than the need to solve a practical problem. I'm not comfortable with the AskDifferent policies, so I'm not arguing it should be closed. I still have the right to dislike such questions, and vote it down.

Comment: @badp: Voting is anonymous by design, but not commenting on the downvote does little to help the person asking the question (or answering) to learn from their mistakes so that they don't lose points in the future, especially for those that are relatively new. As a fellow moderator of a live SE site, I would have expected you to understand that by now. I guess things must be different over at Gaming.

Comment: @Philip Two points is a measly loss that the upvote more than recouped. I didn't want to get involved in a discussion about the downvote, hence my lack of explanation.

Comment: @badp: You could say that for just about any downvote, so my point still stands. And, the OP asked for commentary, so I feel you should have at least obliged the request. I'll just chalk it up to differing value systems.

Comment: @badp Thanks for posting why you downvoted. I understand why you might downvote questions like mine if you don't want to the community to go in this direction, thats a valid opinion. IMHO this site about asking questions related to Apple not just posting problems, also the software-recommendation tag is heavily used on this site. Finally I would say that practicality is subjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more research I have found these games:

- [Galcon](http://itunes.apple.com/app/galcon/id285820845?mt=8) - Swiping multiple weapons to different enemy planets at the same time
- [Bed Bugs](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bed-bugs/id315613006?mt=8) - Swiping away multiple enemys
- [Pinch 'n Pop](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pinch-n-pop!/id293202008?mt=8) - Very similar to Eliss
- [Pinch](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pinch/id351331177?mt=8) - Looks similar to Eliss but with a maze component
- [Touchgrind](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/touchgrind/id297694601?mt=8) - It is also available for OSX but way harder due to not being able to touch the screen directly
- [Touchgrind BMX](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/touchgrind-bmx/id426072035?mt=8) - From the makers of Touchgrind
- [Buggled](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/buggled/id296399693?mt=8) - hold down as many bugs as you can?

I made this a community wiki so edit away.

- [Meeblings](http://appshopper.com/games/meeblings) - Using two fingers, you can activate two of those little guys at once.

Answer (score 0):

- UZU (iPad only) - 1 to 10 finger inputs
- Tesla Toy (similar to UZU but for iPhone)
- Foodies - two fingers maintaining a continuos contact;

Answer (score -2):

Check out Pangolin on IOS. - action puzzler that use two fingers to make trampolines